# Youtube channel membership count

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

## Is there a way to get the count of specific youtube channel memberships? ( not default subscribers )

What I meant by membership are the people who used the paid subscription thing.

###### https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bo5U.png

Like the image above ^^

So, is there a way to count how many members subscribed to pay to a youtube channel?

Comment: Are you able to retrieve this information from the native user interface on youtube.com/studio.youtube.com ? If no, I don't think you'll be able to retrieve this information through an API.